# How do I get programs from C to run in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, c

So I know how HTML works, and I want to try and make a web browser where I can run my program made with C.

It is basically a calculator function program, which the function is written this way:

```c
int calculate(int num1, int num2, char operator)
{
    int sum;
    if (operator == '+')
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
    else if (operator == '-')
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
    /*
        You could already guess how `*` and `/` works.
    */
```

Though it doesn't really work in HTML, as it will only display the code from the program. Best I can do is use JavaScript to make an exact equivalent of the program as a webpage.

How can I rewrite my C program in a HTML file? Should I use JavaScript to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's even possible to run C on any web engines, but even if it is, the hassle would not be worth it. And since it's such a simple program, the best approach would be to simply rewrite it in JavaScript.

```
// Code from Maty1000's answer, which is deleted
function calculate(num1, num2, operator)
{
    var sum;
    if (operator == '+')
    {
        sum = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if (operator == '-')
    {
        sum = num1 - num2;
    }
    else if (operator == '*')
    {
        sum = num1 * num2;
    }
    else if (operator == '/')
    {
        sum = num1 / num2;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: That's a good point. C cannot actually run on HTML, so I would like to try and make the function in JavaScript. @Maty1000 has already made one, so I'll go for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I am aware of to execute compiled C code on the *client* side (within the browser) like you can with Javascript or Python.  Usually C code is executed on the web *server* through the Common Gateway Interface (CGI).

Remember that C is typically compiled to native machine code, not run through an interpreter or virtual machine, so a browser running on an x86 Windows system would not be able to execute code built for a MIPS workstation or vice versa.

The browser would have to implement a virtual machine that the C code is built against.  You really don't want to do that.